# How do I pass a value from a Child view across multiple views in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In my project, I need an id of a 'Product' to be printed to the console when I tap a button. I am accessing an 'id' of a product in one of my child views and printing it to the console (when it is tapped within a child view). I need to use this id in a button in a different view. How do I do this? Here is the structure of the views:

```
struct IntroView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            CustomSelectView()
            Button("Continue") {
                //Here is where the 'selectedProduct' data in ProductRowViewOnboard() needs to be accessed
            }
        }
    }
}
struct CustomSelectView: View {
    @State private var showingProductSheet = false
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Select Product 1")
            }
            .onTapGesture {
                print("Select Product 1 Tapped...")
                showingProductSheet.toggle()
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showingProductSheet) {
                ProductSheetOnboard()
            }
            VStack {
                Text("Select Product 2")
            }
            .onTapGesture {
                print("Select Product 2 Tapped...")
                showingProductSheet.toggle()
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showingProductSheet) {
                ProductSheetOnboard()
            }
        }
    }
}
struct ProductSheetOnboard: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @StateObject var marketplaceModel = MarketplaceViewModel()
    let product_id: String
    var body: some View {
        var columns = Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible()), count: 2)
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        let keyString = defaults.string(forKey: "key") ?? ""
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
            VStack {
                    ForEach(marketplaceModel.filteredProduct, id:\.self){ product in
                        ProductRowViewOnboard(productData: product,  product_id: product_id ?? "")
                    }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
            let keyString = defaults.string(forKey: "key") ?? ""
            self.marketplaceModel.fetchProductTags(key: keyString ?? "")
            self.marketplaceModel.fetchMarketProducts(key: keyString ?? "")
        }
    }
}

struct ProductRowViewOnboard: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @State var selectedProduct : ProductTile?
    var productData: ProductRow
    let product_id: String
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ScrollView {
                HStack {
                    ForEach(productData.products ?? []) { product in
                        ProductView(productData: product)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                selectedProduct = product
//The following print statement works 
                                print("Product id: \(selectedProduct?.id ?? "")")
                                let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
                                let keyString: String? = defaults.string(forKey: "key") ?? ""
                                // The data in selectedProduct here needs to be accessed in IntroView()
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the last view I provided (ProductRowViewOnboard) in the .onTapGesture{}, I have accused the id of the product. I need to access this value in IntroView() so I can use it in the Button.

I can't seem to do it.

Comment: I think you need to rethink the flow of your program. You want to display the selected product in the button, but you are displaying the button and `CustomSelectView` at the same time; ie before a product has been selected. The two different selections in `CustomSelectView` don't make much sense either. In general, you would add a model `@StateObject` in your root view and pass it to the subviews the environment, so that subviews can change properties on this object. You may also want to consider a `NavigationStack` to handle the selection view flows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the state up to where it is needed first and then pass down `let` for read access or `@Binding var` for read/write access, e.g.

```
struct IntroView: View {
    @State var selectedProduct : ProductTile?

    var body: some View {
        ... 
        ProductRowViewOnboard(selectedProduct: $selectedProduct)
        ...
    }
}

struct ProductRowViewOnboard: View {
    @Binding var selectedProduct : ProductTile?
}
```

Also in SwiftUI, the `View` struct should be your primary encapsulation of view data. Don't use view model objects because you'll have trouble getting other view data in and out of them (as you have probably experienced by your non-standard use of `onAppear`); you'll also get consistency bugs which SwiftUI's use of value types for the `View` struct is designed to eliminate.